# Regular expression to exclude special characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regex for a password which meets following constraints in my rails project:

- have a minimum of 8 and a maximum of 16 characters
- be alphanumeric only
- contain at least one letter and one number.

My current regex is:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z])).{8,16}$/
```

This allows me all the restrictions but the special characters part is not working. What is it that I am doing wrong. Can someone please correct this regex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,16}$/
```

The last part of your regex, `.{8,16}`, allows any character with a dot.

The lookahead only makes sure that there's at least one digit and one letter - it doesn't say anything about other characters. Also, note that I've updated your letter matching part - you don't need two character classes.

<sub>Disallowing special characters in a password is totally counter intuitive. Why are you doing that?</sub>

Comment: The only times i've ever seen "alphanumeric only" password requirements, they were because some idiot couldn't be bothered to learn how to sanitize/escape data.  Not that the OP is necessarily that idiot -- i'm going to bet he knows a few, though.

Comment: Well, if it was up to me, I'd let user type all the junk in the world for his password. However sometimes; uniformity with legacy site is more important to business than security. Go figure! :)

Comment: Note, better to use `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$`.  This string matches that regex: `"!\n1234abcd\n#"`

Comment: I'd use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` and `[[:digit:][:alpha:]]` instead of `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.  More descriptive and should allow non-english chars

Comment: glenn, quit complicating things. :)  The regex is fine; if they're going to complain over a freaking **space**, for gawd's sake, what do you think they're going to do with 'ä'?

Comment: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[0-9a-z]{8,16}$/i
the -i option to ignorecase makes it a bit smaller.